# Why does $\lim_{x\to2} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2(x-2))}}{x-2}$ not exist?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2(x-2))}}{x-2}$$

The solution for this problem does not exist but on solving I am getting $\sqrt2$. Why does the limit not exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you started working by enouncing the *wrong* identity $$\frac{\sqrt{\text{stuff}}}{x-2}=\sqrt{\frac{\text{stuff}}{(x-2)^2}}$$ instead of the *correct* one $$\frac{\sqrt{\text{stuff}}}{x-2}=\frac{\lvert x-2\rvert}{x-2}\sqrt{\frac{\text{stuff}}{(x-2)^2}}$$ which would yield the desired discontinuity of sign in $x=2$.

Comment: Love the stuff lol (+1)